# How to load dynamic resources in JSF?

Tags: jsf, resources

I would like to load dynamic resource (generated JavaScript, technically configuration in JSON) as dynamic resource, using `h:outputScript` tag. I'm aware I can do that via writing my own servlet and load it via normal tag scripts, by I would prefer the "JSF-way" of loading resouces.

Is it possible, and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can achieve this by using a specific resource library name and have a custom [`ResourceHandler`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) intercept on it and return a custom [`Resource`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/application/Resource.html) when a resource of the specific library is been requested.

E.g.

```
<h:outputScript library="dynamicJs" name="some.js" />
```

with

```
public class DynamicJsResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

    public DynamicJsResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
        if ("dynamicJs".equals(libraryName)) {
            return new DynamicJsResource(resourceName);
        } else {
            return super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
public class DynamicJsResource extends Resource {

    private String resourceName;

    public DynamicJsResource(String resourceName) {
        this.resourceName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestPath() {
        // TODO: return "/context/javax.faces.resource/" + resourceName + ".xhtml?ln=dynamicJs";
    }

    @Override
    public URL getURL() {
        // TODO: return new URL("http://localhost:8080" + getRequestPath());
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getResponseHeaders() {
        // TODO: return desired HTTP response headers. 
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        // TODO: return InputStream by resourceName.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userAgentNeedsUpdate(FacesContext context) {
        // TODO: return true when resource has been modified in server side.
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>com.example.DynamicJsResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you can also save the boilerplate code and extend from its [`org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.DynamicResource`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/DynamicResource.html) instead so you only need to implement `getInputStream()`. If you don't use OmniFaces, then you can always use its [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/resourcehandler/DynamicResource.java) as guidance.

Comment: Is it possible to register multiple resource handlers, each supporting one library, or that functionality must be merged into single implementation?

Comment: Yes. You can have 0-* `<resource-handler>` entries in `<application>`. They're initialized in the order they appear in the XML.

Comment: OK, but now I'm by implementation I need to provide Resource implementation to DynamicJsResource, or copy the very long code from ResourceImpl...

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to copy the default impl code. It reads the resource from deploy folder and that's not what you want.

Comment: I need to implement such methods as getURL and getRequestPath with no idea how should I do that... PrimeFaces are overgoing it somehow by overloading the method handleResourceRequest(FacesContext context), but by me it was not functioning, instead I got error "Resource referenced by resourceName messages and libraryName i18n not found in call to ResourceHandler.createResource. It will be silenty ignored."

Comment: The DynamicJsResource class cannot extend from ResourceWrapper in your example, because there is really nothing to wrap.